# Change default HTML input validation message

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I want to override the error messages by e.g. Firefox for my HTML5 form with my own personal message. But doing this causes the input field I am applying it to to not allow the form to submit. It's as if you haven't filled in the input field and the error message keeps appearing instead.
HTML part

```
<label for="name">Name</label>
<input id="name" name="name" placeholder="Enter Your Name" required="" type="text">
```

Javascript (IIFE)

```
var change_text = function(){
var name = document.getElementById("name");
   if (!name.checkValidity())  {
        name.setCustomValidity("Please enter your full name"); 
        name.reportValidity();
  } 
    else {
        name.setCustomValidity("");
    }
  }();
```

This does change the message to my bespoke message, but it won't allow the form to submit. Interestingly, if i change my message to an empty sting, it does work (but obviously the error message doesn't show.

Comment: you mean: add an eventListener("submit", function .....?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the `input` and `invalid` events to set your custom validation message.

```js
let name = document.getElementById("name");
name.addEventListener("input", function(e){
  name.setCustomValidity('');//remove message when new text is input
});
name.addEventListener("invalid", function(e){
  name.setCustomValidity('Please enter your full name');//custom validation message for invalid text
});
```

```html
<form>
  <label for="name">Name</label>
  <input id="name" name="name" placeholder="Enter Your Name" type="text" required autocomplete="off">
</form>
```