# HTML Default validation messages styling

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I know that the default validation message **text** can be edited like this

[Change default HTML input validation message](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63491564/change-default-html-input-validation-message)

But I want to know if there is a way to target the default validation message boxes with CSS

[image]

I really like the default validation and this is a research question, I have looked with my browser console to try target the validation message box. But the browser doesn't pick it up.

Let's say I wanted to make the background of the validation message blue and not white or maybe I wanted to change the font-size. Is there any was to target these validation message boxes CSS?

Comment: Might be this one helps you, same question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5272433/html5-form-required-attribute-set-custom-validation-message

Comment: No. Set internally by browser for consistency across all forms user works with

Comment: @Onkar Sorry but that doesn't answer my question. want to know if I can write styles for it

Comment: @charlietfl do you have any links for me to check out please?

Comment: I don't no. Am only about 85% certain of that. There are a variety of browser message features though you can't access from your page code though.

Comment: @charlietfl -That's cool I understand I just want to read up on it so I can better understand :) - Thank you for you help :)

Comment: Could this answer your question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5328883/how-do-i-style-the-html5-form-validation-error-messages-with-css

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At this point the answer seems to be that you can't style the default validation boxes.

Please if anyone has links or a solution to this please add info.

I haven't been able to find anything on this.

If someone adds a viable solution I will accept your answer.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot style the message, but you can create your own "message" element.

Building on the example that you link to, you can add `e.preventDefault()` to stop the default action of displaying the validity message, and then make your own element show up.

#### Update 2023

This is an extended example from the example I did in the first place. Now, there is a "real" message box and when you focus the form again the messages will disappear.

```js
document.forms.form01.addEventListener("invalid", function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  e.target.classList.add('invalid');
}, true);

document.forms.form01.addEventListener("focus", function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  [...e.target.form.querySelectorAll('.invalid')]
    .forEach(elm => elm.classList.remove('invalid'));
}, true);
```

```css
label {
  position: relative;
}

div.feedback {
  border: solid thin red;
  position: absolute;
  left: 10%;
  padding: .2em;
  background-image: linear-gradient(180deg, #fff, #ddd 40%, #ccc);
  display: none;
}

input.invalid~div.feedback {
  display: block;
}

input:invalid {
  border: thin solid red;
}
```

```html
<form name="form01">
  <label>
    <span>Name</span>
    <input name="name" placeholder="Enter Your Name" type="text" required autocomplete="off">
    <div class="feedback">This needs to be a name</div>
  </label>
  <label>
    <span>Email</span>
    <input name="email" placeholder="Enter Your Email" type="email" required autocomplete="off">
    <div class="feedback">This needs to be an email</div>
  </label>
  <button>Submit</button>
</form>
```

Comment: This is not what I asked please read the question properly

Comment: This is actually an excellent answer. Form submissions won't go through when customValidity is set despite the messages not showing. So native validity still plays a vital role, you're just left with the freedom to implement error messages yourself, e.g. as above.

Comment: @AudunOlsen thanks, I updated my answer so that it looks more like a message box. Hope that you (and others :-)) like it.